# Non GPL Swing date picker with keyboard navigation?

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I am looking for a Java Swing date picker that **specifically** allows you to navigate the calendar view using the keyboard. I've only found [JXDatePicker](http://swingx.java.net/) from SwingX, ['DatePicker'](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datepicker) and a couple more that all offer the standard textfield with a button to show the calendar- but none of these allow you to navigate with the keyboard alone.
Use case - imagine your mouse is broken or otherwise unavailable (this is an actual client requirement).

Any pointers? Oh, and I won't touch GPL or similarly licensed stuff with a barge pole - this is for a commercial project.

Comment: have a text only date input...?

Answer (score 1):

Attach key listeners to it.
When user pressed "->" key (right arrow), change month/week/w/e forward.
When user pressed "<-" key (left arrow), change it backward

And so on.

Comment: Yes, I know how it would be done but was hoping someone had implemented it already :-)
Want to avoid reinventing the wheel as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm) may interest you. It has `DateComboBox` and `DateChooserPanel`.